# How can I trigger the jqGrid loading.. message?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I'm intercepting server response via datatype, but I've noticed that the loading.. message
is lacking! How can I trigger it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$(".loading").css("display", "block");
```

Then, to hide it after the data loads, you can use:

```
$(".loading").css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be using the following code.

```
$("#lui_gridName,#load_gridName").show();
```

"gridName" is the name of the grid.

Comment: OR just `$("#load_gridName").show();` which wouldn't grey out the window until the grid loads.